# How to imply continuity of the following sum?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

In my work I constantly run into functions of the following form. Let $X$ be a metric space and $\{x_n\}$ be a countable subset of $X$. For each $n$, we take two open sets ${U_n}$ and ${V_n}$, such that $V_n \subset \bar{V_n} \subset U_n$, where $\bar{V_n}$ is the closure of $V_n$. We assume that $\{U_n\}$ are *disjoint*. On the other hand, take for each $n$ a continuous function $f_n: X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f_n (x_n) = 1$ and $f_n$ is identically zero outside $V_n$. The existence of $f_n$, of course, is ensured by complete regularity of metric space.

Now construct a function
$$
f(x) = \sum_n f_n \mathbf{1}_{V_n}
$$
that is, $f$ equals to $f_n$ on $V_n$ and vanishes outside the union of $\{V_n\}$. My question is: how do we conclude **continuity** of the function $f$?

It seems that the sum does not converge uniformly: for each $n$ we have 
$$
\sup_{x \in X} \sum_{m > n} f_m(x) \mathbf{1}_{V_m}(x) \geq f_{n+1}(x_{n+1})=1
$$
Working locally, i.e., at each point, appears messy to me, as there are cases where $x$ falls in some $V_n$, or falls on the boundary of some $V_n$, or falls outside the union of $\{V_n\}$ and so forth...

Can anyone point a way of concluding continuity of the function?

Comment: if $f_n$ is identically $0$ outside of $V_n$ what is the point of the characteristic function $1_{V_n}$?

Comment: The functions have disjoint support. For every $x$, there is at most one relevant term in the sum. Continuity is a local property. Each point is in some $U_n$, or outside all of the $U_n$.  You are correct it does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Is x_n in V_n?  What is 1v_n?  In the definition of f(x) there is no x in the sum on the right side.